# Git: Commit and push to a different branch from a ignored directory

Tags: git, git-branch

I have the following folder structure in `dev` branch:

```
/base/
     build/
     src/
     package.json
     Gruntfile.js
```

`build` directory is ignored via `.gitignore`. I want to commit and push the files from `build` directory to `master` branch remaining within the `dev` branch.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just checkout on the master branch and edit the .gitignore . once you've finished , checkout on the dev again and reset the .gitignore .

Answer (score 0):

You can forcibly add files that would otherwise be ignored with `git add -f`.

For example, to forcibly add everything in `build`, run `git add -f build`.

Comment: I assume that you would want to make a commit on the current branch, which you could then merge into master later. I doubt it's possible to commit to a different existing branch without switching to it, since the changes may not apply.

Comment: Actually I want to commit and push only the files in `build` directory to `master`. Not merge the whole `dev` branch into `master`.

Comment: If the `build` directory isn't checked in on the `master` branch, you should be able to safely switch to `master` and then commit.